# Org-Babel Clojure Cider NRepl broken?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, org-babel

I followed the instructions [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-clojure.html) and wrote the following org-mode file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (princ (concat (format "Emacs version:\n%s\n" (emacs-version))
                 (format "\norg version: %s\n" (org-version))))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Emacs version:
: GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))
:  of 2016-09-17
: 
: org version: 9.0.5

#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :results value
  (* 6 7)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:

* COMMENT org babel settings
Local variables:
org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil
End:
```

As you can see, the evaluation of the emacs-lisp block works and produces the
expected output. Incidentally, it also reports the versions of things I'm using. However, the clojure source block, when evaluated, leaves

> ```
> Code block returned no value.
> ```

I tried many different Clojure expressions in the code block, such as `println`s and more. Nothing shows up in the NREPL window, and the results in org mode are always the same: the message above in the minibuffer.

in the emacs minibuffer. Here are the specific steps I took:

1. `$ lein new clojure-example`
2. `$ cd clojure-example`
3. `$ emacs clojure.example.org`
4. keyboarded in the file above
5. run emacs command `cider-jack-in`

That produces a repl window with the following version info:

> ```
> ;; Connected to nREPL server - nrepl://localhost:52695
> ;; CIDER 0.15.0snapshot (package: 20170403.402), nREPL 0.2.12
> ;; Clojure 1.8.0, Java 1.8.0_121
> ```

etc.

6. put emacs cursor inside each block and type `C-c C-c`, which is bound to
   `org-babel-execute-src-block`

Prior to that, I inserted the following code in my emacs initialization file:

```
(require 'org)
(require 'ob-clojure)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '( (clojure     . t)
    (emacs-lisp  . t)
    ))
(setq org-babel-clojure-backend 'cider)
(require 'cider)
```

According to the cited instructions.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the current stable release (9.0.5), the org-mode clojure backend is broken and does not work. I submitted a patch which has been applied and I expect will be in the next release.

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30857/clojure-code-evaluation-in-org-mode-produces-no-output/31169#31169